# Filter token module not replacing tokens in custom editor

Tags: 8, forms, tokens

I have created a form with form element

```
class MyForm extends ConfigFormBase {
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['thankyou_paid] = [
            '#type' => 'text_format',
            '#title' => $this->t('Thank you'),
            '#format'=> 'full_html',
            '#default_value' => $config->get('thankyou_paid),
          ];
}
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
    $config = $this->config('subscription.form');
    $config->set('thankyou_paid', $form_state->getValue('thankyou_paid')['value']);
}
}
```

In this editor I add a token [site:name] and in text formats config, I enabled checkbox for  **Replaces global and entity tokens with their values** for full_html format, but this token is not getting replaced with site name.

Anyone can help figuring out what's being missed?

Comment: As side note, the code is not correctly ending a literal string with the string delimiter. (See the first line of the code you are showing, and the one before the last.

Comment: You're not showing how you use and store that text.

Comment: Actually this configuration form is rendering fine, only problem is its text-format does not seem to work, not replacing tokens with their values.